# Loading local data on mysql community server/workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I cant seem to use community server(or workbench for that matter) to use the Load local data infile command for csv. it always says cant use this command its not allowed on this version.

Ps I tried setting the local_infile global variable as 1 in the client cmd prompt but it still gives the same issue.Also i cant seem to give the parameters directly at start since the client opens on its own.(I dont have simple mysql command on windows only community server)

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use load local data infile command in Workbench? It already provides the option for table data import wizard.

Also, for the particular error, I tried following code and it worked for me:

(Before connecting to MySQL database type following)

```
mysql -u username -p --local-infile databasename
Enter Password:
```

Now, try using the database and importing the table.

```
MySQL> use databasename;
MySQL> load data local infile 'filename/filelocation.csv' into table tablename
-> fields terminated by ','
-> enclosed by '\r\n'
-> ignore 1 lines
-> (col1, col2, col3...);
```